# How to retrieve File Version of Assembly Information window in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to programatically retrieve File Version information from Assembly Information window in C# code. So that I can do my further work based on that info. I have given a picture which info I want to retrieve

[image]

So any one have idea how do I retrieve this info???

Comment: what do you mean by assembly file version ?

Comment: @Arshad he means the `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute, usually in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. E.g. `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

Comment: you can check @shah Aharoni answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileVersion;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(YourFilePath);
Console.WriteLine("Assembly Full Name:");
Console.WriteLine(assem.FullName);
AssemblyName assemName = assem.GetName();
Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}.{1}", assemName.Version.Major, assemName.Version.Minor);
```

Comment: That's the assembly version, not assembly file version.